# cross-domain connection not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have to communicate between two servers. I read a tutorial. It is working fine in demo. But when i use it for me, it is not working.

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
url : "http://www.foobar.bar.com/update.php",
data: "name=WE HEART IT",
method : "POST",
crossDomain:true,
cache:false,
success: function(data){
   alert(data);
} 
});
```

PHP (2nd Domain) :

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '>=')  == 1)
  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
else
  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

echo $_POST['name'];

?>
```

Comment: what's the problem? Open Network tab in your console (browser's) and see what's the error.

Comment: Any reason you can't use jsonp?  It makes cross domain stuff a lot easier.

Comment: @dave I think JSONP is difficult. I have to return multiple results. If you still think it is better then can you give a example with short explanation ?

Comment: @HungryCoder In the network tab, the request is not even sent. :(

Comment: you should see at least an OPTIONS call, if that is not the case the problem is not CORS but your JS call

Answer (score 0):

In your options for $.ajax, the `method` property should actually be named `type`.

Check out this link for more details ->
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/